# Real time Grid (JavaScript / jQuery) with specific cell data update

Tags: javascript, jquery, datagrid, grid

I need to update data displayed in the grid every second.

I use jQuery to make an ajax call every second and then I need to bind the data in the grid, but **only** change the **specific** cells that changed/updated.

I am looking for the best JavaScript/jQuery Grid which supports this dynamic 'specific cell update' so only the changes are re-drawn in the HTML and everything else is not 'touched'.

Some plugins/libraries I have tried:

- [DataTables](http://datatables.net) -> All the table is refreshed on data bind.
- [Telerik MVC Grid](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/clientsideevents) -> All the table is refreshed on data bind.
- [ExtJS 4 Grids](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs) -> I think its possible (not sure), but there is a significant learning curve.
- [Wijmo UI Grids](http://wijmo.com/) -> Too many dependencies in order to work (jQuery + jQuery UI + Amplify JS + etc...)
- ... I have checked so many libraries I can't remember all of them :)

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: What database?  And what other infrastructure do you have for accessing the database?  I went through the same ultimately fruitless search,  but it was for a Ruby on Rails site.

Comment: Most of these grid controls have methods for updating the data at least at the row level. None that I am aware of will calculate the "difference" for you. That is going to be your biggest problem, especially doing it quickly enough if you have lots of data. If you can solve that, then you can probably use any one of these grids, by using the proper methods to update a row or a cell directly.

Comment: @RadBrad: The communication with the DB is not the problem here but the display of the data. The data may come from DB or form another source.

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek: Agree with you, but what is the best grid for this kind of thing?

Comment: I'm working on a project with a similar requirement, and wound up writing a desktop application to provide the user interface. Even the fastest grids in the fastest browser couldn't keep up. Desktop app doesn't even break a sweat.

Answer (score 0):

SlickGrid [examples](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Examples) have [async port-render case](http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example10-async-post-render.html) that updates only visible elements.

So you can update data in memory (should be quick), and then find way to tell SlickGrid to re-draw (using async function) only the rows that are displayed now.
So the should be only function, that updates data that may have changed.

Yes, desktop application are better suited, because they have special Listeners/Handler for such case.

Possibly modern JavaScript MVC frameworks have some close ideas implemented.